# How to alter multiple tables at once in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I want to change the character-set of all tables present in my DB. 
        To change character set of one table I can execute it as:

`"alter table mydb.mytable1 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_Ci;"`

But i Have many tables in my 'my db' database.
        List of Tables we can read from information_schema table.
        But i am not sure how to form the Exact query so that with one query I can change character set         of all the tables at once.

Comment: you can alter database.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39465494/819417
SELECT concat('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db_name'
```

Then copy/paste all results and use a db tool or scripting language to run them one by one.

To fix future tables as you add them, run this as well:

```
ALTER DATABASE your_db_name CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

Comment: Thanks +Cees Timmerman that helped out perfectly

Answer (score 0):

[Alter Database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-database.html):

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

> **Note**: Use `"utf8_unicode_ci"` instead of `"utf8_general_ci"`

So if you can't do this with Alter DB then you have to run this for every table individually

Comment: I tried this option. But if I alter database it won't change the character set of columns of the table.

Comment: @Pratik see update. It can't be done with single alter query you have to use them seperatly

Comment: Or is there any script/procedure which can be written?